# Create a function or for-loop to generate tally marks with base R graphics

Tags: r, function, for-loop, graphics

I'm working on a Shiny App that simply generates tally marks.  I have a long script that does a serviceable job, but I'd like to make it more mathematically succinct so that I can eventually use simple inputs for the app.  Right now, the script is as follows:

```
# create dataframe
y=c(rep(c(10, 9), 8))
x = rep(seq(from = 0, to = 3.5, by = 0.5), each=2) 
d = data.frame(x, y)

# Draw empty plot
plot(x=NULL, y=NULL, xlim = c(0, 4), ylim = c(0,10), axes = FALSE, xlab= " ", ylab = " ")

# Begin tallies
segments(d$x[1], d$y[1], d$x[2], d$y[2])
segments(d$x[3], d$y[3], d$x[4], d$y[4])
segments(d$x[5], d$y[5], d$x[6], d$y[6])
segments(d$x[7], d$y[7], d$x[8], d$y[8])
# diagonal 1
segments(d$x[1], d$y[1], d$x[8], d$y[8])

# next tally group
segments(d$x[9], d$y[9], d$x[10], d$y[10])
segments(d$x[11], d$y[11], d$x[12], d$y[12])
segments(d$x[13], d$y[13], d$x[14], d$y[14])
segments(d$x[15], d$y[15], d$x[16], d$y[16])
# diagonal 2
segments(d$x[9], d$y[9], d$x[16], d$y[16])

# Row 2 - revalue dataframe to call upon new y values (this is a clunky step 
I'd like to eliminate as well)
y=c(rep(c(8, 7), 8))
x = rep(seq(from = 0, to = 3.5, by = 0.5), each=2) 
d = data.frame(x, y)

segments(d$x[1], d$y[1], d$x[2], d$y[2])
segments(d$x[3], d$y[3], d$x[4], d$y[4])
segments(d$x[5], d$y[5], d$x[6], d$y[6])
segments(d$x[7], d$y[7], d$x[8], d$y[8])
# diagonal 1
segments(d$x[1], d$y[1], d$x[8], d$y[8])
```

... and so on, for a total of 5 rows.  That generates this plot:
[image]

I'd like to automate the generation of the plot with a for-loop or a function, but my only (admittedly mathematically flawed) attempt generates connected line segments, and I've no idea how to begin automating the crosshatches:

```
plot(x=NULL, y=NULL, xlim = c(0, 4), ylim = c(0,10), axes = FALSE, xlab= " ", ylab = " ")

for( i in 1:16 ) {
  segments(d$x[i], d$y[i], d$x[i+1], d$y[i+1])
}
```

I'm sure I'm just organizing the problem wrong.  This is a frivolous coding project, but any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This draws 1 of your tally marks:

```
sapply(c(1,3,5,7), function(i){ segments(d$x[i], d$y[i], d$x[i+1], d$y[i+1]) })
segments(d$x[1], d$y[1], d$x[8], d$y[8]) # for the diagonals
```

Then it is a matter of translation to generate the other tally marks (a function with 2 parameters, delta_x, delta_y).

Comment: nice - from your sapply function, I'm able to draw all the tallies at once with `y=c(rep(c(10, 9), 8),
    rep(c(8, 7), 8),
    rep(c(6, 5), 8),
    rep(c(4, 3), 8),
    rep(c(2, 1), 8) )
    
x = rep(rep(seq(from = 0, to = 3.5, by = 0.5), each=2), 5) 
d = data.frame(x, y)
plot(x=NULL, y=NULL, xlim = c(0, 4), ylim = c(0,10), axes = FALSE, xlab= " ", ylab = " ")
s <- seq(from=1, to=80, by=2)
sapply(s, function(i){ segments(d$x[i], d$y[i], d$x[i+1], d$y[i+1]) })`.  Will work on the crosshatches next.